# Create constraint on self-referensing relationship in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Question is regarding constraint on self-referencing table.

```
- auto-generated definition
create table users_user
(
    id           serial                   not null
        constraint users_user_pkey
            primary key,
   
    master_id    integer
        constraint users_user_master_id_c8e42c6f_fk_users_user_id
            references users_user
            deferrable initially deferred,
    deleted      boolean                  not null,
    deleted_time timestamp with time zone,
    constraint point_on_itself_check
        check (NOT ((master_id = id) AND (master_id IS NOT NULL)))
);

alter table users_user
    owner to postgres;

create index users_user_master_id_c8e42c6f
    on users_user (master_id);
```

This is reduced version of a table just for example.

In this table I have `master_id` column referencing same table, which separates all records to ones that have  `master_id` Null and ones that have `master_id` pointing to other record in the same table (`NOT NULL`).

My goal is to create a constraint( probably EXCLUSION Constraint) that would check following condition:

--If record has `master_id` pointing to another record in the same table (`NOT NULL`) and this record to which it pointing has `‘deleted’ = True`, than this situation must raise exception.

Or if we have a look from another side of relationship:

– If record(let’s call it `MASTER RECORD`) have `master_id = Null` and `deleted = True`, than there should not be any other records in the same table where `master_id is not null and  master_id == MASTER RECORD id.`

To begin with I can’t figure out which type of constraint should I use?

Any ideas?

Thnaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function to verify the validity of `master_id` and include that in your `check` constraint.

```
morganek=# create table users_user (  -- Dummy table so I can create the function
morganek(#   id int, deleted boolean
morganek(# );
CREATE TABLE
morganek=# 
morganek=# create or replace function users_user_valid_master(v_master_id integer) 
morganek-# returns boolean as $$
morganek$#   select deleted = false 
morganek$#     from users_user
morganek$#    where id = v_master_id
morganek$# $$ language sql;
CREATE FUNCTION
morganek=# 
morganek=# drop table users_user;
DROP TABLE
morganek=# 
morganek=# create table users_user                                                                    
morganek-# (                        
morganek(#     id integer primary key,
morganek(#     master_id integer references users_user(id),
morganek(#     deleted boolean not null,
morganek(#     deleted_time timestamp with time zone,
morganek(#     constraint point_on_itself_check
morganek(#       check (master_id is null 
morganek(#         or (master_id != id and users_user_valid_master(master_id)))
morganek(# );
CREATE TABLE
morganek=# 
morganek=# insert into users_user values (1, null, false, null);
INSERT 0 1
morganek=# 
morganek=# insert into users_user values (2, null, true, now());
INSERT 0 1
morganek=# 
morganek=# insert into users_user values (3, 1, false, null);
INSERT 0 1
morganek=# 
morganek=# insert into users_user values (4, 2, false, null);
ERROR:  new row for relation "users_user" violates check constraint "point_on_itself_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, 2, f, null).
morganek=#
```

The `check` now passes if `master_id is null`.   Otherwise it verifies that the row does not have itself for its parent and then calls `users_user_valid_master()`.

**Update**
The solution failed to protect against deleting a row that has active children.  I broke the solution into separate check constraints as I should have from the beginning.

First drop old objects.

```
 drop table users_user;
DROP TABLE
 drop function users_user_valid_master(integer);
DROP FUNCTION
 drop function users_user_can_delete(integer);
DROP FUNCTION
```

Create functions and the table.

```
 create table users_user (  -- Dummy table so I can create the function
   id int, master_id int, deleted boolean
 );
CREATE TABLE

 create or replace function users_user_valid_master(v_master_id integer)
 returns boolean as $$
   select deleted = false
     from users_user
    where id = v_master_id
 $$ language sql;
CREATE FUNCTION

 create or replace function users_user_can_delete(v_id integer)
 returns boolean as $$
   select count(*) = 0
     from users_user
    where master_id = v_id
      and deleted = false
 $$ language sql;
CREATE FUNCTION

 drop table users_user;
DROP TABLE

 create table users_user
 (
     id integer primary key,
     master_id integer references users_user(id),
     deleted boolean not null,
     deleted_time timestamp with time zone,
     constraint point_on_itself_check
       check (master_id is null or master_id != id),
     constraint valid_master_check
       check (users_user_valid_master(master_id)),
     constraint delete_master_check
       check (deleted = false or users_user_can_delete(id))
 );
CREATE TABLE
```

Verify the constraints.

```
 insert into users_user values (1, null, false, null);
INSERT 0 1

 insert into users_user values (2, null, true, now());
INSERT 0 1

 insert into users_user values (3, 1, false, null);
INSERT 0 1

 insert into users_user values (4, 2, false, null);
ERROR:  new row for relation "users_user" violates check constraint "valid_master_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, 2, f, null).

 update users_user set deleted = true, deleted_time = now() where id = 1;
ERROR:  new row for relation "users_user" violates check constraint "delete_master_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null, t, 2020-07-23 14:56:55.715188+00).
```

Comment: @ Mike Organek . It seem to work only from child side of relations. If i have few childs that point to one parent and then i update his 'deleted' from False to True - nothing happens. Whereas when i want to add child to already deleted parent - from this side all works correctly.

Comment: @AlekseiKhatkevich  Sorry about that.  Please see my updated solution in my answer.  Probably `users_user_can_delete()` should be named `users_user_no_active_children()`.